# How to troubleshoot a goal that has stopped recording completions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a Squarespace website that has a Google Analytics implementation with one goal for visiting a /thank-you page. It has been 48 hours since the last time it recorded a completion despite having 10+ submissions through the form that gates it.

We did add the HubSpot tracking code by code-injection on Squarespace (which is tracking form submissions correctly) at around the time that GA stopped recording completions. Not sure if it might be a conflict of some kind?

My first instinct to troubleshoot would be to uninstall the HubSpot tracking code, but as that is the only thing that is correctly measuring submissions, I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.

We are not using GTM, the GA code snippet is being implemented with Squarespace's Code Injection tool. It is a destination goal.

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Manager? And is this a Destination goal?

Comment: No and yes. I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for updating your question. Here's what I would look into:

1. Is the form still sending people to the thank-you page? (I don't see why it wouldn't be, but this would be a very simple explanation)
2. Are pageviews of the thank-you page still being recorded in the Google Analytics Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report?
3. If #1 is good but you aren't seeing pageviews, then it seems likely the HubSpot code is interfering with the GA code. Are there any errors in the console? Are the two code snippets exactly as they should be? Do you have control over load order so you could force the HubSpot code to load after the GA code?
4. If you are seeing pageviews, then the goal definition is not matching the actual page hits. Is it set to Exactly Matching or something looser? Are there new query parameters that are making the thank-you page have a different URL than the goal is looking for?

If the problem is that the HubSpot code is interfering with people getting to the thank-you page or with GA running, you'll probably need to seek help from them or communities around that code. If the problem is that the goal definition is no longer correct, you should be able to fix it by setting the page to Begins With instead of Equals To.

Good luck!